# Lock ubuntu from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, locking

I usually lock my ubuntu with Ctrl + Alt + L but, I want to run ssh from one machine to other and to be able to lock that machine, is this possible ?

my plan is if possible to run some shell script to lock the second machine.

Comment: lock your own account on the remote host?

Comment: well I want something that will act like I am on the remote machine and I press crtl+alt+l a.k.a lock screen command

Comment: maybe helpful http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615/how-do-you-kick-a-user-off-your-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lock

```
ssh -X user@server "export DISPLAY=:0; gnome-screensaver; gnome-screensaver-command -l;
```

UnLock

```
ssh -X user@server "export DISPLAY=:0; gnome-screensaver; gnome-screensaver-command -d;"
```